# Computer Science Development Path

Tags: php, programming-languages, computer-science

I am Industrial Engineer in Dominican Republic (the Caribbean), i always wanted to Study Computer science when in high school, but i never found in my country a curriculum that seemed as good to decide to take it. Now i realize that i should have taken this path before.

Now following the carrier, i have been learning PHP because is one of the easiest introductions to programming, my question is, can somebody provide me options of a development and learning path for learning with tutorials, books and certificates, enough to enter into a CS master degree?, i am already engineer and i understand much of the mathematical background, what else do i need?

Comment: Can't you just ask your closest university?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would go through introductory courses listed on MIT's Open Courseware and get atleast a basic understanding of what computer science is all about and then start with  basic C# or java programming languages.

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/#electrical-engineering-and-computer-science

Comment: Wicked, i am already doing the introduction to computer science with python and solving algorithms from projecteuler.net with python. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

The specifics of what you'll need really depend on the curriculum of the university you seek a degree from, as well as specifically what you're seeking from a MSCS. The match background you have may or may not need to be extended -- depending again on the curriculum, and also if you do or don't have discrete math in your background.

You're not going to get any solid answers on stackoverflow for this; you really need to talk to an advisor at whichever school you decide to investigate further. The problem is there isn't a general answer that is sure to be accurate for you.

Comment: Mah, thanks for your answer, i am looking for advice , but as a good practice i look for advice in different fronts, in our country computer science is not as well develop as in the united states or other countries, that is the reason for my question. I don't want to be a star (yet) just to have a grasp of the basics.